# How can I reset the score when it comes at certain times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I reset the score when it comes at certain times. For example, when the date is 02.02.2020, the score is reset, but if the player does not enter the game that day, the score is not reset.
I want the game to notice this situation and reset the score. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of when the score was last reset (save it in the player's data files), and when the game is started - check if a "reset date" had occurred between the last reset date and today's date.